# Ionic Form error handling on submit button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

How can I show all the required error when I click on the "submit" button?

[image: Image Reference]

For now, I am showing error when I type on particular input but I also want that when I type on the submit button without entering in input field Then all the errors of every input field must be shown.

[image: Image Reference]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which will return all the form errors by passing all the form controls

just create Interfaces

```
export interface AllValidationErrors {
  control_name: string;
  error_name: string;
  error_value: any;
}

export interface FormGroupControls {
  [key: string]: AbstractControl;
}
```

and create one generic functions which will take form controls as parameters and return errors array

```
export function getFormValidationErrors(
  controls: FormGroupControls
): AllValidationErrors[] {
  let errors: AllValidationErrors[] = [];
  Object.keys(controls).forEach(key => {
    const control = controls[key];
    if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
      errors = errors.concat(getFormValidationErrors(control.controls));
    }
    const controlErrors: ValidationErrors = controls[key].errors;
    if (controlErrors !== null) {
      Object.keys(controlErrors).forEach(keyError => {
        errors.push({
          control_name: key,
          error_name: keyError,
          error_value: controlErrors[keyError]
        });
      });
    }
  });

  return errors;
}
```

How to use in your case

when click on submit button just pass like this

```
submit(){
    const error: AllValidationErrors[] = getFormValidationErrors(
      this.SignupForm.controls
    );
    console.log(error);
}
```

hope this will help you

and if you want any required errors controls than you can filter it

```
let requiredarr = error.filter(a => {
      return a.error_name === "required";
    });
    console.log(requiredarr);
```

let me know if you need anything more.

thanks

kushal shah